# How to get this widget to display on mobile version?

Tags: css, mobile, widget, blogger

In my blogger blog, I have two widgets in one 'b:section'. First one is a popular post widget and other is a fluid size youtube video widget. Both widgets properly display on desktop version. They also display on mobile version when watched mobile version from a desktop. But when in a real mobile only the first widget(popular posts) displays. And also when at the mobile version from a desktop, if the desktop window width decreased to a mobile size, second widget(youtube video) disappears.

But, when the disappearing second widget is put in top as first widget in 'b:section' both widgets display in a real mobile too correctly and there's no problem at all.

Please help me to get these both widgets displayed on a real mobile without changing the widgets order. Codes of the two widgets in the 'b:section' are as below.

Also any of youtube video widgets in any 'b:section's after the first widget of this 'b:section' isn't displayed in a real mobile.

```
<div id='widget_tab'>
<div class='tabs-inner' id='tab1'>
<ul>
<!--Enter-Tab-1-Content-Here-->

<b:section id='tabs-1' preferred='yes' showaddelement='yes'>
  <b:widget id='PopularPosts1' locked='false' mobile='yes' title='Popular Posts' type='PopularPosts'>
    <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:if cond='data:title'><h2><span><data:title/></span></h2></b:if>
  <div class='widget-content popular-posts'>
    <ul>
      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
      <li>
        <b:if cond='data:showThumbnails == &quot;false&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:showSnippets == &quot;false&quot;'>
            <!-- (1) No snippet/thumbnail -->
            <a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a>
          <b:else/>
            <!-- (2) Show only snippets -->
            <div class='item-title'><a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a></div>
            <div class='item-snippet'><data:post.snippet/></div>
          </b:if>
        <b:else/>
          <b:if cond='data:showSnippets == &quot;false&quot;'>
            <!-- (3) Show only thumbnails -->
            <div class='item-thumbnail-only'>
              <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnail'>
                <div class='item-thumbnail'>
                  <img expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:post.thumbnail' height='40px' width='40px'/>
                </div>
              </b:if>
              <div class='item-title'><a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a></div>
            </div>
            <div style='clear: both;'/> 
          <b:else/>
            <!-- (4) Show snippets and thumbnails -->
        <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnail'>
            <img expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:post.thumbnail' height='55px' width='60px'/>
<b:else/>
            <img alt='no image' height='55px' src='http://rccigmimg.com/_u7a1IFxc4WI/TTjruHJjcfI/AAAAAAAAAk0/i11Oj6i_bHY/no-image.png' width='60px'/>
        </b:if>
        <a expr:href='data:post.href' expr:title='data:post.snippet' rel='bookmark'><data:post.title/></a>
            <div style='clear: both;'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
      </li>
      </b:loop>
    </ul>
    <b:include name='quickedit'/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
  </b:widget>

  <b:widget id='HTML6' locked='false' mobile='yes' title='' type='HTML'>
    <b:includable id='main'>
  <!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
    <h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
  </b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <data:content/>
  </div>

  <b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
  </b:widget>

</b:section>



</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you share a demo blogspot blog on which you are facing this issue?

Comment: I already got over this problem, but thank you for replying!